# Parsing nested JSON objects in a CSV file with golang

Tags: json, csv, parsing, go

I'm trying to parse a CSV file which contains a JSON object in the last column.
Here is an example with two rows from the input CSV file:

```
'id','value','createddate','attributes'
524256,CAFE,2018-04-06 16:41:01,{"Att1Numeric": 6, "Att2String": "abc"}
524257,BEBE,2018-04-06 17:00:00,{}
```

I tried using the parser from `csv` package:

```
func processFileAsCSV(f *multipart.Part) (int, error) {
  reader := csv.NewReader(f)
  reader.LazyQuotes = true
  reader.Comma = ','
  lineCount := 0
  for {
    line, err := reader.Read()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    } else if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
        return 0, err
    }

    if lineCount%100000 == 0 {
        fmt.Println(lineCount)
    }
    lineCount++
    fmt.Println(lineCount, line)
    processLine(line) // do something with the line
  }

  fmt.Println("done!", lineCount)
  return lineCount, nil
}
```

But I got an error:

> Error: line 2, column 0: wrong number of fields in line,

probably because the parser ignores the JSON scope which starts with `{`.

Should I be writing my own CSV parser, or is there a library that can handle this?

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CSV input doesn't follow normal CSV convention, by using unquoted fields (for JSON).

I think the best approach would be to pre-process your input, either in your Go program, or in an external script.

If your CSV input is predictable (as indicated in your question), it should be easy to properly quote last element, using a simple `strings.Split` call, for instance, before passing it to the CSV parser.

Comment: I suspect preprocessing the file would be difficult because the input file (which may be huge) is arriving via network and is being processed while it is incoming (notice `multipart.Part`).

Comment: Not at all. Just create an `io.Reader` wrapper, that reads each line as it comes in, calls `strings.SplitN(input, 4)`, properly quotes/escapes the last field, then writes the modified line as output.